# How to print the search results after form_submit, in a custom search module?

Tags: forms, database, blocks, search

I am creating a custom search block, I have created a form in the block. Here is my form_submit. I need to print a html table of some of the fields in the $result array. I am using Drupal_set_message(), I need to show the results in a table instead, so that user can print the page

```
$text = $form_state['values']['text'];
$query = db_select('table_1', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('id'));
 $query->fields('n', array('phone'));
$query->fields('n', array('name')); 
$query->condition('n.p_id', $text, '=');
$column_name = $query->execute();
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you're asking. Are you wanting to know how to print an HTML table in drupal_set_message() or parse out the results of DB query?

Comment: I want to print  a html table with drupal_set_message() or in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I used an if statement in the form to check if submit is pressed and gave the results in the if block.

```
function hook_form($form, &$form_state) {
if (!empty($form_state['values']['text'])) {//here i am checking if the text field is empty
    $header=array('one'=>t('one'),'two'=>t('two'));//your header
 $query=db_query();//query
$column_name = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();//fetchAssoc to get results in an associative array.
//here get the fields from $column name into rows
$row = array( 
    array(
    'one'=>$column_name[""],
    'two' => $column_name[""],
    );
//your form elements after submit is pressed.  
 $form['table']=array(
 '#theme'=>'table',
 '#header'=>$header,
 '#rows'=>$row,
 );

}
else {
//your original form here.
 $form['text'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield'
 );
$form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit Button'),

);
  }
 return $form;
}
```

in you form submit add this

```
$form_state['rebuild']=true;
```